# Sum of Greatest Common Divisor (GCD)

Tags: c++, math

Calculate

[image: %E2%88%91i%3D1n%E2%88%91j%3D1ngcd%28i%2Cj%29]

n <= 1000000 (1e6).
If there is just one test, my code is OK, but if there are 100000 (1e5) test, what should I do to improve my code?

For example:

> **Input:**
> 60
> 604 84 940 659 989 497 400 656 805 169 305 141 718 691 500 723 658 405 903 859 992 228 614 971 947 621 730 930 416 592 198 351 68 464 347 505 634 364 663 148 385 836 801 515 915 493 836 543 452 931 395 772 461 689 654 625 16 483 819 788

> **Output:**
> 664481  8779  1728829  800375  1926541  436636  272512  794360  1237943  41094  150180  27601  964846  888763  442011  979955  799717  279099  1588154  1421789  1944288  79683  687732  1851177  1754783  706093  1002087  1690021  296284  636364  58576  204764  5419  375448  198625  450938  737167  221753  812718  30739  250692  1342475  1225124  469651  1630287  427113  1342475  526336  354587  1694011  263465  1129495  369081  882688  789434  716388  204  409663  1285603  1180671

I had some mistakes (Code edited 1 time)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

long long t, n, sum, d[1000010];

int main()
{
    cin >> t;
    for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++){
        cin >> n;
        sum = 0;
        for (int k = n; k; k--){
            d[k] = (n / k) * (n / k);
            for (int j = k + k; j <= n; j += k)
                d[k] -= d[j];
            sum += d[k] * k;
        }
        cout << (sum - n*(n+1)/2)/2 << '\n';
    }
}
```

The contest from here: http://ntucoder.net/Problem/Details/5610

Comment: WHile it's legal, nesting for-loops using the same variable name is a very poor practice. You have nested loops defining a new copy of variable i.

Comment: There will almost certainly be some math trick that obliterates most, if not all, of the work.  If you do not know or discover this trick, you won't be able to process the given input within the time or other resource constraints given.

Comment: @user4581301 What are those math tricks?

Comment: Seem O(n^(3/2)) way exists. Is this suitable for given limitations?

Comment: using a simple sort, you can calculate all the results in a single scan. and add to each result only if i, j <= n.

Comment: which specific test is failing? does it take too long?

Comment: @Alessandro Teruzzi Yes, T ~ 1000 is failed, it's TLE

Comment: @SHR It's not easy if i = k, k+1, ..., n

Comment: The summation is equivalent to: `sum{N, i = 2} . sum{i - 1, j = 1} . gcd(i, j)` ; the inner summation is: `P(i) - gcd(i, i)` -> `P(i) - i`, where `P(i)` is the [gcd-sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillai%27s_arithmetical_function). This can be computed from the factorization of `(i)`.

Comment: @Brett Hale, Code using Euler totient function is Time limited Exceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a late reply after leaving comments. I was looking back at my 'stackoverflow snippets' directory, and realised I had implemented a solution for this question (67689345), and forgot about it...

The key is to find an analytic expression for the gcd *sum*, which requires the factorization of `(n)`. see: [Pillai's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillai%27s_arithmetical_function), or: [The gcd-sum Function](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL4/BROUGHAN/gcdsum.pdf)

Tabulating all prime factors for `(n <= 1000000)` at runtime is so fast that it's almost negligible to the total running time. However, I used a [utility](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brettyhale/mrtab/master/sptab.c) of mine to generate a table of all primes `(p) <= (1000)`. It actually finds all primes up to `(1024)`, but that's fine. `sp_factor` yields a prime factorization with *multiplicity* if a prime factor occurs more than once, so any repeated factors must be handled in the `gcdsum` function. These are required for the prime *power* exponents in any case.

Note: each `(n)` is factored to find the summation of gcd terms. We exploit the transform of the index of summation to yield:

[image]

Note, that the summation for `(n <= 1000000)` may exceed 32-bits. So a 64-bit accumulator is used. On an *old* laptop I'm using just now - a 2Ghz dual-core i7 - this takes less than (0.25) seconds, which should be well within the contest requirements.

The results for: `n = {1, .., 5}` match the [contest](http://ntucoder.net/Problem/Details/5610) values: `{0, 1, 3, 7, 11}`, while: `n = 1000000` yields: `4071628673912`

```
/******************************************************************************/

#include <inttypes.h>

/******************************************************************************/

static const uint16_t sp_lut[] =
{
    0x0002, 0x0003, 0x0005, 0x0007, 0x000b, 0x000d, 0x0011, 0x0013,
    0x0017, 0x001d, 0x001f, 0x0025, 0x0029, 0x002b, 0x002f, 0x0035,
    0x003b, 0x003d, 0x0043, 0x0047, 0x0049, 0x004f, 0x0053, 0x0059,
    0x0061, 0x0065, 0x0067, 0x006b, 0x006d, 0x0071, 0x007f, 0x0083,
    0x0089, 0x008b, 0x0095, 0x0097, 0x009d, 0x00a3, 0x00a7, 0x00ad,
    0x00b3, 0x00b5, 0x00bf, 0x00c1, 0x00c5, 0x00c7, 0x00d3, 0x00df,
    0x00e3, 0x00e5, 0x00e9, 0x00ef, 0x00f1, 0x00fb, 0x0101, 0x0107,
    0x010d, 0x010f, 0x0115, 0x0119, 0x011b, 0x0125, 0x0133, 0x0137,
    0x0139, 0x013d, 0x014b, 0x0151, 0x015b, 0x015d, 0x0161, 0x0167,
    0x016f, 0x0175, 0x017b, 0x017f, 0x0185, 0x018d, 0x0191, 0x0199,
    0x01a3, 0x01a5, 0x01af, 0x01b1, 0x01b7, 0x01bb, 0x01c1, 0x01c9,
    0x01cd, 0x01cf, 0x01d3, 0x01df, 0x01e7, 0x01eb, 0x01f3, 0x01f7,
    0x01fd, 0x0209, 0x020b, 0x021d, 0x0223, 0x022d, 0x0233, 0x0239,
    0x023b, 0x0241, 0x024b, 0x0251, 0x0257, 0x0259, 0x025f, 0x0265,
    0x0269, 0x026b, 0x0277, 0x0281, 0x0283, 0x0287, 0x028d, 0x0293,
    0x0295, 0x02a1, 0x02a5, 0x02ab, 0x02b3, 0x02bd, 0x02c5, 0x02cf,
    0x02d7, 0x02dd, 0x02e3, 0x02e7, 0x02ef, 0x02f5, 0x02f9, 0x0301,
    0x0305, 0x0313, 0x031d, 0x0329, 0x032b, 0x0335, 0x0337, 0x033b,
    0x033d, 0x0347, 0x0355, 0x0359, 0x035b, 0x035f, 0x036d, 0x0371,
    0x0373, 0x0377, 0x038b, 0x038f, 0x0397, 0x03a1, 0x03a9, 0x03ad,
    0x03b3, 0x03b9, 0x03c7, 0x03cb, 0x03d1, 0x03d7, 0x03df, 0x03e5,
    0x03f1, 0x03f5, 0x03fb, 0x03fd, 0x0000
};

/* 172 primes < 2^10 factor 83.87% of all odd integers. */

/******************************************************************************/

static inline unsigned int sp_factor (uint32_t p[], uint32_t n)
{
    uint32_t sp = sp_lut[0], q;
    unsigned int np = 1;

    /* assert(n > 1 && n < (UINT32_C(1) << (20))); */

    for (unsigned int i = 1; (q = n / sp) >= sp; )
    {
        if (q * sp == n)
            np++, n = q, *p++ = sp;

        else if ((sp = sp_lut[i++]) == 0) /* EOT entry: */
            break;
    }

    *p++ = n;

    return np; /* the number of prime factors (with multiplicity). */
}

/******************************************************************************/

static uint64_t gcdsum (uint32_t n_max)
{
    uint64_t sum = 0;

    /* assert(n < (UINT32_C(1) << (20))); */

    for (uint32_t n = 2; n <= n_max; n++)
    {
        uint32_t ptab[(20)], pn, gn = 2 * n - 1;

        if ((pn = sp_factor(ptab, n)) != 1) /* composite: */
        {
            uint32_t etab[(20)], un, p, i;

            etab[0] = 1, un = 1;

            for (p = ptab[0], i = 1; i < pn; i++)
            {
                uint32_t pi = ptab[i];

                if (pi == p)
                    etab[un - 1]++;
                else
                {
                    ptab[un] = (p = pi), etab[un] = 1;
                    un++;
                }
            }

            for (gn = 1, i = 0; i < un; i++)
            {
                uint32_t pi = ptab[i], ei = etab[i];

                gn *= ((ei + 1) * pi - ei);
                while (--ei) gn *= pi; /* pi ^ (ei - 1) */
            }
        }

        sum += gn - n; /* exclude (n, n) term from summation. */
    }

    return sum;
}

/******************************************************************************/
```